# C# code to find the end range of excel sheet data using Data tables

Tags: c#

I am trying the find the Excel Row position to get the END point for my data fetch Range for excel using SSIS script component. I am using Datatable in a Script task to facilitate this.
In the below example my sheet range always starts with 1. I need to get the end position by searching "End of data" in the range A2:A10

[image]

Below is the Code I am using

```
string currentable ="Sheet1$"
string strSQL = "Select * From ["+currentTable+"A2:A10]";
int iCnt = 0;
OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, excelConnection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
objAdapter.Fill(ds, currentTable);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[currentTable];


foreach (DataRow  row in dt.Rows)
{
    MessageBox.Show("In for Loop");
    iCnt = iCnt + 1;
    MessageBox.Show(row[iCnt].ToString());


}
```

In this code I am getting the following error

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column 1.

I need to browse through the First column of the excel and search the string "End of Data"  and get its position.

Any ideas/help

Thanks

Comment: I think column A would be index 0 wouldn't it (you are incrementing your column index for each row by the looks of it)?  So then you do not need iCnt at all - row[0].ToString() would be the contents of column A then you could probably just check that for the string you are looking for (I'd have thought, though, it would be more efficient to do it with a where clause but I have no idea if that would work).

Comment: Aren't you missing a "$" after your sheet name and before your range?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a bit of an error in the code above. The SQL used to select data selects a single row, but the for loop looks at the second column (iCnt + 1) when only one column is present (row[0]).

Regardless, something like this might work for your needs:

```
var lastRow = dt.Rows.AsEnumerable().Select((row, index) => new { Name = row.ToString(), index }).First(row => row.Name == "End of data").index;
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I thought it would return me 10 rows. I am trying the code you gave. It is giving an error saying "System.Data.DataRowCollection" does not contain a definition for "AsEnumerable".

Do i need to import any class for this.

Comment: I do not have the Linq related DLL files . Is there a way we can convert this code using For loop. Please let me know